# PHP7.2 missing intl extension

Tags: php, php-7.2, intl

I'm trying to run php app that use `locale_accept_from_http` function from intl extension. My php version is `7.2` and I get an error: `Call to undefined function locale_accept_from_http()`;

I was trying:

**1. Install extension `sudo apt-get install php-intl`**.
   The error is:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>       requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>       distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>       or been moved out of Incoming.
>       The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>       php-intl : Depends: php7.1-intl but it is not going to be installed
>       E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**2. Enable intl extension in php.ini.**
  I'm getting a warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl'

What is the right way to use this extension with `php7.2`?

Comment: Was PHP installed via apt too? What error do you get from `apt-get install -f php7.2-intl`?

Comment: @JonStirling php is installed via apt. I get `Unable to locate package php7.2-intl`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As it states in your error, you are having broken packages so in that case, you should try to fix it, probably following commands will fix them.

```
apt update
apt autoremove
```

Once you have fixed that issue, you can try executing following commands if you have not added ondrej PPA:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
apt install php7.2 php7.2-intl
```

Comment: This worked for me for php7.4 ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: is it safe to say `apt install php7.2` when php 72 is already installed (production server). I have installed `php7.2-intl` alone but there is no intl.so module available to load

Comment: Worked for me with PHP 7.3, executing `apt install php7.3-intl` was enough.